# Overhead of calling the same virtual function in a loop

Tags: c++, performance, loops, templates, virtual-functions

I have some code that has a structure something like this:

(`doStuff2()` will be called through a `Class1` pointer. That will call `doStuff()` in a loop. There are multiple classes like `Class3` so `Class2` will have multiple template instances.)

```
struct Class1{

    virtual void doStuff2() = 0;

};

template<typename T> struct Class2 : public Class1{

    virtual void doStuff() { /*code*/};

    void doStuff2() override {

        // Call this in a huge loop.
            doStuff();

    }

};

struct Class3 : public Class2<SomeType>{

    void doStuff() override final { /*code*/};

};

//...

void someFunc(Class1 *p_class1){

    p_class1->doStuff2();

}
```

My questions: Is there a way to call `doStuff()` in a non-virtual way so there is no overhead? Would making it pure-virtual in `Class2` and final in `Class3` help?

Does calling the same virtual function in such loop have all the performance problems of virtual functions?

Comment: If you really need runtime dispatch, you have to use virtual and so you have to pay for it. If not, write code which will refelect this. We often see questions which asks for speed drop for a virtual call. Do you have an idea what the real overhead of a single vpointer call is? What do you believe it takes to the rest of a real world application? The only thing which really helps: Measure your final code! And believe: Compilers are much better as you believe!

Comment: I am really uncertain why `/* code */` and not a [mcve] in there and why the meaningless function names.  Is `doStuff()`'s implementation supposed to have the loop you go on about in it?  Or are you talking about some other loop?  Why not put a loop there?  How many `Class3`s style types are there per `Class2<X>` for a fixed type `X`?  Are there more than one `Class2` templates? (`Class2` is a template class, not a class; `Class3` meanwhile seems to represent a category of classes, despite same naming pattern, and `Class1` a is unique type?)

Comment: Oh and the short version is "have you tried CRTP?"  Those questions are aimed at decoding if CRTP would work, which is unclear from your description.

Comment: I think you want to optimize a non existing bottleneck. The cost of a virtual dispatch is laughably low in the context of a real program. Even if you find a way to remove the virtual dispatch with anything faster the performance gain will be so slim, that it wont save you the time you spend on worrying about it.

Comment: @churill There is the dispatch code itself, and then there is the lack of inlining.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have some good advice on why this might be premature optimization, but to answer your question directly:

> Is there a way to call doStuff() in a non-virtual way so there is no overhead?

If you have a fixed set of types, then you can runtime-dispatch non-virtual methods by way of a tagged union, ala `std::variant`:

```cpp
using Class1 = std::variant<Class2<SomeType1>, Class2<SomeType2>>;
/*...*/
std::visit([](auto&& c) { c.doStuff(); }, p_class1);
```

Which roughly optimizes down to some good-ol' C-style switching:

```cpp
switch (p_class1.class_type) {
    case CLASS2_SOMETYPE1:
         ((Class2<SomeType1>)p_class1).doStuff();
         break;
    /*...*/
}
```

> Does calling the same virtual function in such loop have all the performance problems of virtual functions?

Modern processors are pretty good at indirect branch prediction, so you probably won't see much overhead calling a virtual method in a loop.